# PHP: Converting Image to TIFF with imagemagick

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am trying to convert and image to a tiff using imagemagick but am running into a problem when trying to write the file. I get an error that says:

> Unable to open image...
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2584'

This is the code I am using:

```
$im2 = new Imagick($image);
$im2->setImageFormat("tiff");
$im2->setImageColorSpace(5); 
$im2->writeImage("test.tiff");
```

$image is just a url I am passing to an image file. I am just running a simple test function to get it to work and put a test.tiff in the same folder.  What could I be doing wrong here? Having trouble finding much documentation on this.

Comment: Does it work with a local file?

Comment: The file is local on the server. I'm doing the same thing with other imagemagick scripts, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument of the `Imagick` constructor is to load a local image file. To load a remote image file, you should instantiate an `Imagick` object without arguments and either:

- download the image content and pass it to the `readImageBlob` method, or
- `fopen` the URL and pass it to the `readImageFile` method.

For example:

```
// assuming $image is an URL or path to a local file
$handle = fopen($image, 'rb');
$im2 = new Imagick();
$im2->readImageFile($handle);
$im2->setImageFormat("tiff");
$im2->setImageColorSpace(5);
$im2->writeImage("test.tiff");
fclose($handle);
$im2->destroy();
```

Comment: The error I am getting is when it is trying to write the file.. not open the file.  Sorry, should have been more clear, it is: unable to open file test.tiff.

Comment: doh, it was because of file permissions. Sorry, your answer did help though.

Comment: I don't know why you didn't just use Imagick::readImage — Reads image from filename.

Comment: I wasn't sure `Imagick::readImage` worked with URLs apart from filenames. I've just tested it and it does. So, yes, you could use `$im2->readImageFile($url);` and skip the `fopen`/`fclose` part. Good tip.

Answer (score 2):

Imagick works with local files and remote files.

```
$im2 = new Imagick($image);
$im2->setImageFormat("tiff");
$im2->setImageColorSpace(5); 
$im2->writeImage("test.tiff");
```

It would work equally well in both remote and local server.
The pfunc already said is permissions error.
Another case that this error occurs is the definition of the directory incorrectly.
sorry my en