# unable to convert image into tiff

Tags: php, imagick

I am trying to convert image into tiff and bmp although this code work fine in case of bmp but the image created by this code for tiff is not a valid image .when i trying to open tiff file in MS photo viewer it will not opening and says it is damaged

this is the code

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->readImage( realpath('../im/a.jpg') );
$im->setImageFormat('tiff');
$im->writeImage( "e://new.tiff");
$im->destroy();
```

why this code not work for tiff format although it work for jpeg png and bmp.I am using ImageMagick-6.7.7 with php 5.5.9

i have also check supported format by imagick using queryFormats and tiff is in the list then why it is not created a valid tiff image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728687/php-converting-image-to-tiff-with-imagemagick

Comment: $im->setImageFormat("tiff"); then 
$im->setImageColorSpace(5);

Comment: @Anni Can you post the 'damaged' tiff somewhere? And/or use a different image viewer?

Comment: @RachelGallen Why do you think setting a new image space would have any effect? That linked issue is for problem on reading the file, not generating it.

Comment: `$im->setImageColorSpace(5);` not create an effect it is still not valid tiff file

Comment: i think reading of image is not a problem as it worked when i set format `bmp` or `png`

Comment: the code is not work only when i set format tiff

Comment: @Anni did you read the stackoverflow question?

Comment: @RachelGallen I read it and it doesn't appear related to Anni's problem - why do you think setting the colorspace to COLORSPACE_LAB (=5) would help?

Comment: @Danack have you any idea about my problem.what i am doing wrong

Comment: @Anni I have no idea, because you haven't given enough information. As  I said before, can you post the 'damaged' tiff somewhere? And/or use a different image viewer? If ImageMagick is generating the tiff file, but it's damaged in some way, there's no way to tell what the problem is from the information you've given.

Answer (score 0):

TIFF requires special library package installed alongside imageMagick, LibTIFF v.3.6.1 or newer. Confirm this is installed?

http://www.libtiff.org/